# Differences between SQLite database in Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, porting

I an tasked with porting and Android app I built some months ago over to iOS.

Now, I have also worked with SQLite in iOS in the past. However, I remember it being a lot more work than the Android equivalent. Especially in relation to querying.

In Android I was able to perform a query using the following command (see below), where **db** is an instance of SQLite, **dbName()** is a method that returns the name of the DB, **getFieldNames()** returns a array of field name Strings and **where** contains the where clause.

```
Cursor result = db.query(dbName(), getDBFieldNames() , where,null,null,null,null);
```

I want to use such a nice and clean **db.query** command in the iOS version of SQLite3. However, does it (or something like it) exist, because I can't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you will be using the C api for sqlite, which is a bit more difficult to use than the Java one. It is certainly very different, so don't expect it to work identically.

You should check out the sqlite documentation for using [sqlite with C/C++](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up completely re-implementing and came up with a great solution. Now I have an extensible class/object  to provide simple objects an easy way to commit themselves to a dB. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Kekoa is right. Alternatively, you can use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) in iOS, which gives you a nice (but still pretty lightweight) wrapper around SQLite. The API will be a little different than the one you're familiar with, but FMDB gets you out of the weeds of the SQLite C interface.

---

Thus, in FMDB, you can open a database with:

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
```

You can open your record set like so:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select rowid,* from test where a = ?", @"hi'"];
```

You can iterate through the rows of your result set like so:

```
while ([rs next]) {
    // just print out what we've got in a number of formats.
    NSLog(@"%d %@ %@ %@ %@ %f %f",
          [rs intForColumn:@"c"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"b"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"a"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"rowid"],
          [rs dateForColumn:@"d"],
          [rs doubleForColumn:@"d"],
          [rs doubleForColumn:@"e"]);
}
```

And you can close your result set like so:

```
[rs close];
```

Comment: I wish I could flag two answers. I gave you a point anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a tool to help with simple access to a SQLite database on both iOS (with ARC) and Android. The tool takes in a sqlite database file and autogenerates base classes and some helper classes to handle the CRUD queries. There's also examples of how to use it for iOS and Android. I hope this can be helpful.  https://github.com/pl4u/flyingdb